# Returning various strings based on date in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an advent calendar where a new question is asked every day, but currently, nothing is displayed. The current code is as following:

The controller in **app.js**:

```
.controller('textCtrl', function($http) {
  this.data = {};

  $http.get('js/text.json').success(function(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }.bind(this));

  var that = this;

  var dato = new Date().getDate();

  this.getSpm = function(x) {
    switch (x) {
      case 5: return that.data.femdes;
      case 6: return that.data.sekdes;
      case 7: return that.data.sjudes;
      case 8: return that.data.åttdes;
      case 9: return that.data.nides;
      case 10: return that.data.tides;
      case 11: return that.data.elldes;
      case 12: return that.data.toldes;
      default: return 'Spørsmålet har ikke kommet ennå';
    }
  }

  this.dagens = this.getSpm(dato);
})
```

In the HTML file:

```
{{text.dagens}}
```

For some reason, nothing is displayed. No errors in the console either.

Comment: This is not correct angularjs style. First I would remove `.bind(this));` Second, read about building controllers here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers It will help you a lot

Comment: When removing `.bind(this));` all the text on the entire website disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the field `this.dagens = this.getSpm(dato);` before the data has been returned from the server,

You should put the above line inside the `$http` request:

```
$http.get('js/text.json').success(function(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.dagens = this.getSpm(dato);
 }.bind(this));
```

Comment: I always thought JavaScript code was executed chronologically. Thanks for this.

Comment: Basically it does, but the `$http` is an AJAX request, that's why you have the callback function that is being asynchronous executed once the server responded (It might that a few milliseconds for the response, but it can also that a lot more then that)